# Terraform is throwing InvalidArgumentException when enabling dynamic partitioning for kinesis firehose stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt, amazon-kinesis

Even though I am following the terraform documentation to enable dynamic partitioning exactly (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream) I keep getting the following error:

**Error: error creating Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream: InvalidArgumentException: Dynamic Partitioning Namespaces can only be part of a prefix expression when Dynamic Partitioning is enabled.**

I am completely confused why I am getting this error as the processing_configuration enabled is set to true so I am not sure why it is giving me an error in which it is saying dynamic partitioning is not enabled at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream) for dynamic partitioning is incomplete.
What they don't mention is that you also need to specify a `dynamic_partitioning_configuration` block to enable it.

```
dynamic_partitioning_configuration {
  enabled = "true"
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream#dynamic_partitioning_configuration

Comment: The seem to have added the docs now